# Why is this sql query running so slowly? Large table with detailed string filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query below is running on a ~20000 row table. Each customer has 1-3 customer contacts. This particular query is taking more than 6 seconds to run despite only returning 11 rows. Which part is killing it?

```
SELECT C.Id,
       CASE
           WHEN CT.Name = 'Residential' THEN ISNULL(CC.FirstName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(CC.LastName, '')
           ELSE C.CompanyName
       END AS FullName,
       C.CustomerTypeId,
       CT.Name,
       ISNULL(CC.PhoneNumber, '') AS PhoneNumber,
       A.City,
       S.Name,
       A.Street,
       A.Zip,
       C.TaxExempt,
       C.Active,
       ISNULL(C.CompanyName, '') AS CopmanyName,
       ISNULL(CC.FirstName, '') AS CustomerContactFirstName,
       ISNULL(CC.LastName, '') AS CustomerContactLastName
FROM [dbo].[Customer] C
JOIN Address A ON A.Id = C.AddressId
JOIN State S ON A.StateId = S.Id
JOIN CustomerType CT ON CT.Id = C.CustomerTypeId
LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerContact CC ON CC.CustomerId = C.Id
AND CC.Active = 1
AND CC.[Primary] = 1
WHERE (0 = 1
       OR C.Active = 1)
 AND
    (CT.Name +'|'+ ISNULL(CC.PhoneNumber,'') +'|'+ S.Name +'|'+ LTRIM(A.Street) + '|' + LTRIM(A.Zip)       
            + CASE WHEN CT.Name = 'residential' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(CC.FirstName, ''))) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(CC.LastName, ''))) ELSE '' END
            + CASE WHEN CT.Name != 'residential' THEN LTRIM(C.CompanyName) ELSE '' END
            + CASE WHEN C.TaxExempt = 1 THEN 'tax Exempt' ELSE '' END
            + CASE WHEN C.TaxExempt = 0 THEN 'taxable' ELSE '' END
            + CASE WHEN C.Active = 1 THEN 'active' ELSE '' END
            + CASE WHEN C.Active = 0 THEN 'not active' ELSE '' END
    )
    LIKE '%' + CASE WHEN lower('jake') = 'null' THEN '' ELSE lower('jake') END + '%'
ORDER BY FullName
OFFSET 0 ROWS       -- skip rows
FETCH NEXT 150 ROWS ONLY; -- take rows
```

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag based on the syntax.  In the future, you should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Well, for starters that WHERE clause is forcing your query into a RBAR operation.  That's always a killer for database queries on any platform.

Comment: `lower('jake') = 'null'` makes no logical sense as do a number of other expressions in your where clause. Is this query the result of a larger, more complex process that dynamically generates the statement you posted?

Comment: @SMor yeah sorry I didn't explain that well. You're right that this query is dynamically generated normally. This is just hard-coded example I'm using for testing. The 0=1 is normally AllowInactive=1. And 'jake' is normally GlobalFilter

Answer (score 0):

Basically like statement always costing time
in below query within case statement whichever record matching case condition it will return first so no need to search for other conditions 
Hope so you got your answer

```
            SELECT C.Id,
                       CASE
                           WHEN CT.Name = 'Residential' THEN ISNULL(CC.FirstName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(CC.LastName, '')
                           ELSE C.CompanyName
                       END AS FullName,
                       C.CustomerTypeId,
                       CT.Name,
                       ISNULL(CC.PhoneNumber, '') AS PhoneNumber,
                       A.City,
                       S.Name,
                       A.Street,
                       A.Zip,
                       C.TaxExempt,
                       C.Active,
                       ISNULL(C.CompanyName, '') AS CopmanyName,
                       ISNULL(CC.FirstName, '') AS CustomerContactFirstName,
                       ISNULL(CC.LastName, '') AS CustomerContactLastName
                FROM [dbo].[Customer] C
                JOIN Address A ON A.Id = C.AddressId
                JOIN State S ON A.StateId = S.Id
                JOIN CustomerType CT ON CT.Id = C.CustomerTypeId
                LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerContact CC ON CC.CustomerId = C.Id
                AND CC.Active = 1
                AND CC.[Primary] = 1
                WHERE (@VARIABLE1 = 1
                       OR C.Active = 1) 
                 AND CASE WHEN isnull(@variable,'') !='' THEN
                 CASE WHEN Lower(C.CompanyName) like '%' + lower(@variable)+'%' THEN 1
                 WHEN Lower(CC.FirstName) like '%' + lower(@variable)+'%' THEN 1
                 WHEN Lower(CC.LastName) like '%' + lower(@variable)+'%' THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 END 
                 ELSE 0 END =1

                ORDER BY FullName
                OFFSET 0 ROWS       -- skip rows
                FETCH NEXT 150 ROWS ONLY; -- take rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this approach actually made the query slower. I agree with what you're saying but the amount of time saved by short circuit evaluation is negligible since for 99% of the rows, all of the when clauses will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the execution plan. Your request is not sargeable, which means you don't use indexes correctly.
First, don't use functions in the where clause (case, lower, isnull...). You should have calculated columns with indexes on them instead if you can't already insert good datas into the columns.

Try avoiding like '%xxxxxx'. Non sargeable if the percent isn't at the end of the string.

Avoid using left join. Sometimes it is better to do your request and store results into a temporary table and then use a left join on it.

Finally, you should try some indexes with included columns.